# How to traverse all directories in windows install with multiple drives

Tags: python, linux, windows

I'm writing a script that should be cross platform (usable by laymen without needing to edit the code).
The script will basically traverse through all the directories on the computer and process some of the files found.
The snippet of code in question is as follows:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/"):
    for file in filenames:
        #process files
```

So on Linux this works fine since "/" is the root directory. However, on windows, the "/" translates to C:\, which means that on a computer with multiple drives (C:\, D:\, E:\ etc) Those other drives won't be processed.

How can I make sure all the files on all the drives are processed in both Windows and Linux with one script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (untested) example which checks for drives if the machine is not a linux platform:

```
import sys
if sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2":
    drives = ['/']
else:
    # http://nullege.com/codes/search/win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings
    import win32api
    drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
    drives = drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]

for drive in drives:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(drive):
        # ...
        pass
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to check positively for Windows rather than "anything other than linux"?  Is there some issue with doing it that way?

Comment: For sure, you could explicitly check for MS Windows, Mac OSx, or anything else listed here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform